# pass a variable inside an array to update that variable dynamically - in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i'm trying to change variables dynamically so as not to use too many switch statements. i was hoping to do this:

```
this.variable1 = 2
this.variable2 = 3

var array1 = [this.variable1, this.variable2]
```

and then later do

```
array1[0] = 25
array1[1] = 12

console.log(array1[0]) //would output 25
console.log(array1[1]) // would output 12
```

of course it this is not what happens which is normal but how can i achieve that dynamically? There must be a way i'm sure.

Comment: What happens instead? Please add the full code.

Comment: How can i improve this question. I was banned but i cannot seem to fix this.

Comment: You could start by not ignoring the comments asking for more information.

Comment: Of course but there was no other code to show, it was an example i was giving to try to understand. Why would i be penalized for something i cannot provide?

Comment: But the example you posted does exactly what you claimed it does not do. So nobody was able to reproduce the problem, hence you were asked for the observed behaviour and your exact code (not just a wrong example).

Comment: I see, ok. This is because in actionscript in flash it was working. I don't work with it anymore so i can't provide much more info but that is what i was trying to get clarification on. Thank you for your feedback. So tell me what can i do now to get out of this ban? It is really hurting my ability to ask question and interact on so.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: I read that but it says to edit my questions but i don't see what that does. Can you just at least upvote my question for the sake of helping me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/3067/

```
var array1
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    variable1: 2,
    variable2: 3
  },
  mounted() {
    array1 = [this.variable1, this.variable2]
  },
  methods: {
    test() {
      array1[0] = 25
      array1[1] = 12

      console.log(array1[0]) //would output 25
      console.log(array1[1]) // would output 12
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hello Again Potray, ok so i didn't get the subtlety of the situation. Your answer is correct by actually my problem is different i realized. I was also trying to access a textfield this way from the array. 


var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    textfield_phone: 'phonetextfield', 
  },
  methods: {
    selecttextfield1() {
      this.focusInput(this.textfield_phone, 1000) //this works
    },
  }
})

Comment: i didn't get the subtlety of the situation. Your answer is correct by actually my problem is different i realized. I was also trying to access a textfield this way from the array. 


 variable1: false,

 function1() {

      this.variable1 = true //this works of course console.log(this.variable1) prints true
 },

function2() {

 var temparray1 = [this.variable1]
temparray1[0] = true //does not work like i want, it's the value in the array that change, not this.variable1

console.log(this.variable1) //prints still false
console.log(temparray1[0]) //prints true

Comment: Potray, so how do you solve this issue of pointing to object in javascript? don't you usually have a need to create some sort of table in js when you can give instructions? I mean if you have this outcome change this variable. A table would be perfect instead of a big switch statement.

Comment: If you need to solve another problem please post another question. I can't really understand the code in your comment since there are comments that I can't see where they end.

Comment: How can i improve this question to get out of my ban, i got a -1 on here when i was trying to ask a genuine question.